# Lodash check whether an array is array of object?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I couldn't find any Lodash method that can differentiate between a normal (e.g. integer) array and array of objects, since JavaScript treats object as array.

like both will return true

```
console.log(_.isArray([1,2,3])); // true
console.log(_.isArray([{"name":1}])); // true
```

Comment: Well.. actually "array of object" is array too. Furthermore array may contain both objects and scalar values

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `_.every`, `_.some`, and `_.isObject` to differentiate between arrays of primitives, arrays of objects, and arrays containing both primitives and objects.

### Basic Syntax

```
// Is every array element an object?
_.every(array, _.isObject)
```

```
// Is any array element an object?
_.some(array, _.isObject)
```

```
// Is the element at index `i` an object?
_.isObject(array[i])
```

### More Examples

```js
var primitives = [1, 2, 3]
var objects = [{name: 1}, {name: 2}]
var mixed = [{name: 1}, 3]

// Is every array element an object?
console.log( _.every(primitives, _.isObject) ) //=> false
console.log( _.every(objects,    _.isObject) ) //=> true
console.log( _.every(mixed,      _.isObject) ) //=> false

// Is any array element an object?
console.log( _.some(primitives, _.isObject) ) //=> false
console.log( _.some(objects,    _.isObject) ) //=> true
console.log( _.some(mixed,      _.isObject) ) //=> true
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just want to check whether a property has object or not, I need not to check everything, imagine I have one object has 100 nested object and array object, __.some is overkills.

Comment: Ok, so you just want to check at a single index? That isn't too hard. I can add that to the basic syntax above.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. See the edited Basic Syntax section above.

Comment: hey i found some problem. https://jsbin.com/vuluzejetu/1/edit?html,js,console isObject doesn't work as expected. lol.

Comment: Could you paste the code here? It's not showing for me on JSBin, all I see is `isArray` and a space afterwards in the JS section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137411/discussion-between-alex-yong-and-gyre).

Comment: This should fix it, adding `[0]` after each array: https://jsbin.com/totoniwiju/edit?js

Comment: oh why? I thought it receive an object?

Comment: It should receive an element from the array you want to test. The index in the brackets can be whatever, but I would go with 0 (meaning the first element).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job

```js
_.every(yourArray, function (item) { return _.isObject(item); });
```

This will return `true` if **all** elements of `yourArray` are objects.

If you need to perform partial match (*if at least one object exists*) you can try `_.some`

```
_.some(yourArray, _.isObject);
```

Comment: both _.every and _.some loop through ur entire set of property, how to check on specified property's value?